# Flutter: http post upload an image (Futuer<file>)

Tags: http, flutter, dart, file-upload, httprequest

I get an image by image picker and I am also displying it in future file.
The issue that I hava that i cant send it by URL.

the parameter

```
  Future<File> _profliePicture;
```

The image picker:

```
 _pickImageFrom(ImageSource imageSource) async {
    setState(() {
      _profliePicture = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: imageSource);
    });
  }
```

My url file sender:

```
upload(File imageFile) async {    
  print("starts to upload...");
    var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(imageFile.openRead()));
      var length = await imageFile.length();

      var uri = Uri.parse("URL");   
     var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
      var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length,
          filename: basename(imageFile.path));
          //contentType: new MediaType('image', 'png'));

      request.files.add(multipartFile);
      var response = await request.send();
      print(response.statusCode);
      response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
        print(value);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Is there any error you get?

Comment: yes i cant call the function at all because when i put my picture it cant assigned to parameter type file